# Uninstall SourceTree using cmd or powershell

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, cmd.exe, uninstall

I would like to use **cmd** or **powershell** commands to uninstall *SourceTree* from windows 10 machines on my network. The reason I need a *terminal* way is that I have to do this remotely and simultaneously for multiple PCs that happen to have this app installed.

Usually I would go to the installation path and then run *uninst.exe* or *uninstall.exe* or the app would have some flags for uninstalling. This one doesn't seem to have any *special flags*. An other way I tried is to create a .bat script and remove the files manually and **AppData**, but it is too tedious to manually clean the **registry** in this case.
Can someone help me with this ?

Comment: You might use PowerShell, WMI and Windows Package Management to do this: https://4sysops.com/archives/uninstall-programs-remotely-with-powershell/

Comment: This doesn't work for whatever reason.

Answer (score 1):

I did little research and was able to find a cmd way to uninstall it.
To uninstall it using *cmd* I was looking on the *Process Explorer* for *cmd line* of the *msiexec.exe* which gave me the command below

```
"C:\windows\system32\msiexec.exe" /qb /x {C2F82CF6-50FA-41FE-8000-1361A76223FA}
```

The last part, **{C2F82CF6-50FA-41FE-8000-1361A76223FA}**, is the app unique identifier (GUID).
One way to find it is using the WMI command below:

```
wmic product get IdentifyingNumber, Name | findstr "SourceTree"
```

This could leave some files installed on `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Atlassian` depending on how it was installed.

---

**PS:** *I randomly get -1 vote for no reason and most of the time without an explanation of why I deserve -1 vote! Is there something wrong with this community?*